# Add checkbox in stringgrid Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, checkbox, firemonkey, tstringgrid

for an app, I have a stringgrid with objects. now it is the intention that the objects are selected in the string grid by means of the checkbox. so for every row, there must be a column with a checkbox. what is the best way for this on an FMX platform? Or is there a way you can add a column in the SQL database with checkboxes?

Comment: After you have added a `TStringGrid` to your form, right-click it and select `Items Editor`. Then use the `Items Editor` to add a `TCheckColumn` among the string columns.

Comment: When I do that and I fill the grid with the data from SQL then the checkbox column doesn't show up.

Comment: It is quite impossible to suggest anything more as you have not shown how you are populating the `TStringGrid` from the SQL. How about providing a [mre]?

Comment: @TomBrunberg There is no code for the string grid I fill it with bind visually. that's the only thing that is linked to the string grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem and did it like this. First, I added a column in SQL with a bit value. In Delphi a linked it to a memtable with the boolean value. Now I bind the string grid visually to the memtable so the string grid filled with the SQL data. when you right-click on string grid you see 'columns editor..' click on that and you see the columns from the SQL. now click on the boolean column and change the column type to Tcheckcolumn.